# Unable to hide the sub Header

Tags: jquery

I have got two Items inside the JSON Array as shown

```
[
    {
        "name": "Item  1",
        "value": [
            "None",
            "Honey with Butter"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Item  2",
        "value": [
            "None",
            "None"
        ]
    }
]
```

(**None** Indicates there are no Topping selected for that Item)

If there aren't any Toppings for an Item , i must hide the **Toppings** Header for that Item

This is my jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/ksmzzaeo/

I have tried it this way

```
var toppingstyle = "none";
var divhtmltoppings = '';


for (var l = 0; l < toppings.length; l++) {
  var toppingsul = '<ul>';
       $.each(toppings[l].value, function (i, text) {
                if (text != '' && text != undefined&&text!='None') {
                    toppingsul += "<li>" + text + "</li>";
                }
            });
    var item =  l + 1;
    if(toppingsul!='<ul>')
    {
        toppingstyle = 'block';
    }
   divhtmltoppings+='<h5>Item '+item+'</h5><h6 style="display:'+toppingstyle+'">Toppings</h6> '+toppingsul;
  }
  $('.crust-topping-detailsWrap').append(divhtmltoppings);
```

Could any please tell me how to achieve this ??

This is my jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/ksmzzaeo/

Comment: add a counter for valid toppings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making the heading visible if there are toppings, but you don't make it invisible if there are no toppings, so once a heading is visible all the rest of them become visible.

Set a `none` style when there are no toppings:

```
if(toppingsul!='<ul>')
{
    toppingstyle = 'block';
} else {
    toppingstyle = 'none';
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/ksmzzaeo/4/

Note: You have no `</ul>` that matches the `<ul>`, so the items will be nested in each other. Adding one would be something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/ksmzzaeo/5/

Answer (score 1):

you just have some strange check here

```
  if (toppingsul != '<ul>') {
        toppingstyle = 'block';
    }
```

see the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ksmzzaeo/1/

Comment: Removing that check just hides all headings.